# How can I dm a user only with the ID?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (message.content.includes('!test')) {

        var mention = message.mentions.users.first().id;

        console.log(mention);
        message.mention.send('test')
}
```

I tried this code and if I type in the chat !test it console logs the ID. Now my question is how I send a DM to the ID. Thanks for helping

Comment: I was about to edit your last post for readability and answer it, do you still need an answer for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let user = client.users.cache.get(mention);
user.send('Test DM');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
client.fetchUser('id number here').then((user) => {
user.send("Message");
});
```

This is for existing version v11, for more information related to classes on discord.js, you can find it here at this [link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

This is to coders who wanna jump into v12 you can start [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start)

Comment: this is Discord.js v11 and earlier only. (FYI)